# Is this a security flaw for Other, Others, Others... accounts having 0 (root) UID?

Tags: security, macos, user-account, parallels-desktop

When running this command `dscl . -list /Users UniqueID`, I get duplicate UID, for the Other, Others, Others... accounts, which is the same UID root uses.

```
daemon              1
Guest               201
myusername          501
nobody              -2
Other               0
Other...            0
Others              0
postgres            502
root                0
```

I'm worried if this might be a security issue after I've updated from Yosemite → El Capitan (10.11.1), and I'm not aware if it was present before the update.
I've found out about this after being unable to install Parallels Deskop 10. The message from parallels was:

**ERROR: 15476. Cannot install Parallels Desktop because there is a non-root user account with the UID 0 in your system**

So this leaves me questioned whether it's a Parallels issue or the permission configurations.

Comment: On the Mac systems I have access to, there are no user accounts called **Other** with UID 0. Are you aware of any software that might have created these accounts? Is your Mac managed by an IT department or a private computer?

Comment: I remember messing around with that a few months ago, I think I was doing something like this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/how-to-get-rid-of-the-other-account-on-the-login-screenm, my reason was to remove the "Others" from the login screen while I was on Yosemite. My Mac is not managed by anyone other than me, hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each user on OS X should have a unique identifier.

Given that your Mac is not managed and that you do not want the three **Other** accounts, reassign these accounts to different UID values – or delete them.

See [Accidentally created user with duplicate UID. How to fix?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182579/accidentally-created-user-with-duplicate-uid-how-to-fix) for steps on how to reassign or remove these errant accounts.

This `dscl` command should work and form the basis for removing the other two accounts:

```
dscl . -delete /Users/Other
```

Be careful and please **take a back-up first!**

Comment: A bit worried if I can mess the system somehow if they are involved in some system processes, as the Others login was available before. Is there a way to check if they are safe to remove?

Comment: So long as you make back-up first, an alternative approach is to install a clean OS X and migrate back in your personal account. Hopefully someone who has seen this specific situation before will be along to share their experience - and any warnings!

Comment: In the end deleting all of these users solved the issue for me, and things seem to be working normal afterwards. It may be possible that I've created all of these three users to be able to hide them from the login screen, based on some tutorial.